# Get all the timestamp values from a range, within the past 24 hours

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

I have a Google Forms data where I only want to perform the past 24 hours of inputs. The formula I am using is:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY('Production Log'!A:A,"Select A where hour(timevalue(now())-timevalue(toDate(A))) <=24"))
```

But I am getting this error:

> Error
>   Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: PARSE_ERROR: Encountered " "hour" "hour "" at line 1, column 16. Was expecting one of: "(" ... "(" ...

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Filter` may be simpler:

```
=filter('Production Log'!A:A,(now() - ('Production Log'!A:A)) < 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=QUERY('Production Log'!A:A,
 "select A 
  where A = date '"&TEXT(TODAY()-1, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'", 0)
```